# Rails - Call a method from within a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to call a method I've defined from within a string, which is passed as a parameter to the where method, like so:

```
existing_size = self.exchange_rates.where("? < date_valid", :time).size
```

The method is:

```
  def date_valid
    date = Date.today
    if(Time.now.hour >= HOUR)
      date += 1.day
    end
    date
  end
```

However, I get the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "date_valid" does not exist
       LINE 1: ...xchange_rates"."prediction_id" = $1 AND ('time' < date_valid...
```

Comment: Have you completed all your db migrations? Looks like column missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though you have your `time` attribute and `date_valid` method swapped in your `where` call. This is of course assuming that `time` is, in fact, a column in your `exchange_rates` table. The following should work for you.

```
existing_size = self.exchange_rates.where("time < ?", date_valid).count
```

I've also used `count` instead of `size` because `count` does the calculation in the database, while `size` does it in memory on the returned `exchanged_rates` relation.